# Options available to a programmer on the Main Game Loop

Tags: graphics, real-time, physics, frame-rate, game-loop

Could one of you please give me a bit of insight to each one of these 4 topics, I am just a little confused on what it is asking.

I have a good idea on what passive and active rendering are, and that the use of active rendering is more sutable for games programming.

I'm just not to sure about the rest.

---

The timing of the main game loop is an important component of any computer game, since it impacts on the frame rate and the real-time physics calculations needed to make the game run at a realistic (or at least playable) rate. You are required to read up on the programming issues that affect this timing, and write a report that covers the range 
of options available to a programmer. Your report should consider the following headings:

1. The distinction between active and passive rendering, and an explanation of the preferred mode for a game program.
2. The division of time between the physics (or game-model) update and graphics update stages, and an explanation and analysis of the relative importance of these in a game that involves real-time physics calculations.
3. Techniques for achieving accuracy in real-time physics, and an explanation of the trade-offs that may be necessary to do this.
4. Programming techniques that can be used to try to keep the frame-rate for graphics updates to some desired rate.

---

Comment: This should probably be on: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, will post it there now. Are you able to give any insight to the question in the mean time? If not thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Asked on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/options-avaiable-to-a-programmer-on-the-main-game-loop